# socks.py argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Tags: python, google-oauth, socks, pydrive

i'm using pydrive on a remote server (pythonanywhere), when i run the code it asks for verification code, and when i provide the code i get the following error

```
Go to the following link in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=685978119888-2fbsd3hmbmdjf11l976t1bma0thepekl.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google
apis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&response_type=code
Enter verification code: 4/wwGmzGdLZlTik2zijZS4fjzAfbt-JvstslPApcT68rcnL2ObgW9EKg0
```

above is the verification block.
i get the following error when i enter the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hedihadi/aw.py", line 18, in
uploadimg("h","h","e")
File "/home/hedihadi/aw.py", line 7, in uploadimg
gauth.CommandLineAuth() # <--
File "/home/hedihadi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 125, in _decorated
self.Auth(code)
File "/home/hedihadi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 495, in Auth
self.Authenticate(code)
File "/home/hedihadi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 508, in Authenticate
self.credentials = self.flow.step2_exchange(code)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2054, in step2_exchange
http, self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request
connection_type=connection_type)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/init.py", line 1957, in request
cachekey,
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/init.py", line 1622, in _request
conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/init.py", line 1528, in _conn_request
conn.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/init.py", line 1309, in connect
sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 406, in connect
self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0],destpair[1])
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 357, in __negotiatehttp
while resp.find("\r\n\r\n")==-1:
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str
```

this is my `aw.py` file, where i run the code and get the error

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

def uploadimg(kart, band, fraction):
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.CommandLineAuth() # <--
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': "lqi"+fraction+"bandi"+band+"karti"+kart})
file1.SetContentFile("hi.jpg")
file1.Upload()

file3 = drive.CreateFile({'id': file1['id']})
uploadimg("h","h","e")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a free account, so you need to configure PyDrive to use the PythonAnywhere proxy. Details of how to do that can be found in an issue on the PyDrive Github and the proxy details are available in the PythonAnywhere help pages.

Comment: can you please give more details, give links, I can not find information on how to do this